# Where do I find help with naming that song?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following.

> **What is the name of this song?**
>
> This dance track has been on my mind for days and I cannot think of its name! All I can remember is the lyrics of "I know I'll make it through with you" with a tune that [goes like this](https://we.tl/t-jbGgWRMyR6).

It looks like music is for music theory questions, so this is probably most suited elsewhere. I would be grateful of a poke in the right direction!

Comment: Asked at [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/12234/11330) as suggested. Thanks all!

Comment: How about you just google it: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=lyrics%3A+%22I+know+I%27ll+make+it+through+with+you%22

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [Music Fans site](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com).

It seems its [most popular tag](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tags) was [identify-this-song](/questions/tagged/identify-this-song), but unfortunately it has recently changed its scope and such questions are no longer on topic.

I'm afraid there isn't any other site that offers a general alternative at this time.

Comment: It's a shame that Music Fans has changed that policy. Perhaps we should have an identify stack.

Answer (score 10):

### No such site

Music Fans changed their scope after years of lukewarmly accepting questions like that: [Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733)

The only other sites that do accept some forms of music ID would not be appropriate. For example, [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) would accept an "identity this song" question but only if it was about science fiction or fantasy, or even something featured in such a work.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) is the best choice, it already has a solid [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) tag with the following tag wiki:

> Use this tag if you want to identify a  song.
>
> Questions should have **as much as details as possible**:
>
> - Youtube or soundcloud link.
> - Detailed description (Radio, TV channel, date, genre, language, country...).
>
> Read:
> [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-should-i-do-to-improve-my-identification-question)
>
> There should be exactly **one** correct answer — when someone does
> suggest the correct answer, please accept it, so that everyone else
> knows that there is no point making any other suggestions.
>
> ---
>
> ### External links
>
> - Database of information about sampled music or sample-based music, cover songs and remixes, [WhoSampled](https://www.whosampled.com)
> - Database of information about music from TV shows and movies:[TuneFind](https://www.tunefind.com/)

Comment: Regrettably, Music Fans has now banned song ID questions: [Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/733/identification-questions-are-now-off-topic-heres-our-next-steps)